# Liferay portlet: A simple hour glass or rotating wheel or progress bar example

Tags: jsp, liferay, progress-bar

To make evidence of a long process in progress, I need to show a simple example to place an hour glass or progress bar or similar animation over the JSP after I had clicked on the submit button of a form in that JSP page, and I'm waiting for the end of the process action phase before to show the next JSP page.

An example is the little whell Liferay shows when you click on a submit form, obscurating the JSP.

This is not related to upload of a file to the server.

It is a simple example to show something waiting the end of a long process phase.

Thank you in advance !

Ivano C.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement progress bar with aui :

[Progress Bar](http://alloyui.com/tutorials/progress-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `liferay-portlet.xml` has the correct `ajaxable` and `render-weight` configuration set. [Check the DTD](http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_2_0.dtd) - here's an excerpt:

```
<!--
The default value of render-weight is 1. If set to a value less than 1, the
portlet is rendered in parallel. If set to a value of 1 or greater, then the
portlet is rendered serially. Portlets with a greater render weight have greater
priority and will be rendered before portlets with a lower render weight.

If the ajaxable value is set to false, then render-weight is always set to 1
if it is set to a value less than 1. This means ajaxable can override
render-weight if ajaxable is set to false.
-->
<!ELEMENT render-weight (#PCDATA)>

<!--
The default value of ajaxable is true. If set to false, then this portlet can
never be displayed via Ajax.
-->
<!ELEMENT ajaxable (#PCDATA)>
```

With this, your portlet might take as long as it needs, but the full page will already be delivered - just your long-running portlet is displaying a spinner until it's actually loaded asynchronously.

Check this by adding `Thread.sleep(5000)` to your portlet's view.jsp (with proper exception boilerplate)

(this is also used by Liferay's stock RSS portlet: If it fetches slow RSS feeds, it'll also run asynchronously. You might experience it there, first hand)

Comment: Olaf Kock ! It worked ... but how to get the beautiful effect as Liferay do to obscure the background with a transparency beside the rotating reel ?